# Error 3011 VBA exporting all tables to txt in access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm new to Visual Basic and I'm trying to export all tables in ms access to a text file.

And I have this code

```
Function save2txt() As String

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

On Error GoTo errHandler

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Set db = CurrentDb

For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    ' ignore system and temporary tables
    If Not (tdf.Name Like "MSys*" Or tdf.Name Like "~*") Then
        Debug.Print tdf.Name
        DoCmd.TransferText transfertype:=acExportDelim, specificationname:="ExportSpec", tablename:=tdf.Name, FileName:=Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\" & tdf.Name & ".txt", hasfieldnames:=True
    End If
Next

Set tdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

errHandler:

   Debug.Print Err.Number & " " & Err.Description


End Function
```

The first 3 tables get exported to .txt and then I get error 3011. When I try to export manually a window pop up saying that a field doesn't exist. I'm using the specification that is saved using the wizard to export.

This is what appears in MSysIMEXSpec:

```
DateDelim:  /
DateFourDigitYear:  -1
DateLeadingZeros:  0
DateOrder:  0
DecimalPoint:  .
FieldSeparator:  ,
FileType:  1252
SpecId: 2
SpecName: ExportSpec
SpecType:  1
StartRow:  0
TextDelim:  
TimeDelim:  :
```

Comment: Try it without the `SpecificationName` parameter. Also, add an `Exit Function` statement before your `errHandler:` label. If some of your tables demand a `schema.ini` file, you may have to specify a different file for each table.

Comment: I can't remove `SpecificationName` because it returns me `error 3441`. I'm using comma as a field separator and so overlaps with decimal separator

Comment: Using a comma as the decimal separator is inconsistent with this `MSysIMEXSpec` line: `DecimalPoint:  .`. You could try changing the field separator. But you still may need to make one or more `schema.ini` files in order to get all your tables to export correctly.

Comment: It only shows the decimal error when I try it wihtout the `SpecificationName` parameter. I've tried creating a schema.ini with only `Format=Delimited(,)` and `DecimalSymbol=.` but it doesn't seems to work. Does the columns of all tables need to be same size to export using a Export Specification? Because the first three get exported, it only stops when get to a larger one

Comment: I just don't have enough information to help you further. Schema.ini is well documented, and there is plenty of searchable help online. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this same problem and what I've found is that one of the tables has a different field name than what is defined in the specification. You will have to create a different specification for the table with a column name that does not exist in the others.